# creating blocks for addObserverForName:object:queue:usingBlock:

Tags: ios, objective-c, callback, block

Can someone show me how to create block for this method that holds multiple parameters as I only know how to create blocks for a single parameter method.
addObserverForName:object:queue:usingBlock:

Comment: What do you mean? The block in this method only takes hype notification as the parameter. You can't use a block with different parameters.  What are you trying to do?

Comment: I'm trying to complete a challenge in a book and it ask to create block for this method. How can i do it otherwise.

Comment: It depends on what you want to do.

Comment: Oh ok i found the answer already. Tks for the help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What I do is sending a single parameter that is actually an NSDictionary ... so I can send lot of information in a single parameter.
GL HF

Answer (score 0):

The notification center method addObserverForName:object:queue:usingBlock: has a fixed block signature for the block that gets invoked. You can't add additional parameters to the block.

However, that isn't usually a problem. Blocks inherit the scope in which they are defined. If you pass a block to the notification center from an instance method of an object, all the instance variables and properties of the object that makes the call are available, as are local variables in the actual method that makes the addObserverForName:object:queue:usingBlock: call.

The system plays some games to make that happen. Local variables are copied from the stack to the heap at the time the block is passed.

Referring to "self" in a block is generally a bad idea however. That can cause the object (self) to be retained and create retain cycles. In that case I usually create a local variable "myself" that points to self and set it up at the beginning of the method.